# Laravel seeder failing silently

Tags: laravel, seed

Hey I am just starting to get moving with laravel and I can't seem to make the seeder work.  The code that follows fails silently:

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();
        $this->call('SettingsTableSeeder');
        // $this->call('GenericTableSeeder');
        // $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

SettingsTableSeeder.php

```
<?php
class SettingsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

   public function run()
   {
       $settings = Settings::create(array(
          'adPriceStandard' => 9
       ));
   }
}
```

Settings model (Settings.php)  :

```
<?php
class Settings extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'settings';
}
```

the model is there and the DB is in place, and I can access the settings table.  I run the seeder and nothing happens.  I AM STUMPED.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things to keep in mind for anyone who finds this post and encounters a similar issue.

First, make sure you run 'composer dump-autoload'.

Second make sure that you either:
A) have $table->timestamps(); inside of your model's database migration, or

B) Set public $timestamps = false; in your Model class.

If you leave out $table->timestamps(); and forget to set public $timestamps to false, db:seed will fail silently.

If you're still having an issue after the above, create a new route at /test and include your Model::create([..]) code inside of it. This should throw a visible QueryException.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `Settings` model? Are you extending `Eloquent`? It is possible that Eloquent is looking for the table `settingss` based on your class name. You can set your table's name in your `Settings` model like this :

```
protected $table = 'settings';
```

Comment: Ok, I have added my Settings model to my question.

Comment: @TrassVasston Are you running the Artisan command `php artisan db:seed` when seeding your DB? Do you know if your `run` method in the `SettingsTableSeeder` is called? Maybe put a echo here to test.

Comment: @AntoineAugisti, I added a Log::info() statement, but it does not put anything in the log.  So...  perhaps it is not doing anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I write my seeders - its a bit different to yours - see if this works;

```
<?php
class SettingsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

   public function run()
   {
       $settings = array('adPriceStandard' => 9);
       DB::table('settings')->insert($settings);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using early laravel 5.1 build. You're missing `Eloquent::reguard()`. Also when using `::create([])` make sure all fields that added using this function is `fillable`. Please refer to the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations) more regarding migrations.

ps. this is random guess, could you include namespace for Settings class in `Settings::create(array(`. although i'm sure such problem throws class not found exception.